# How to send the build to already provisioned remote person's iPhone

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

We have provisioned 3 devices for our iPhone development. 2 developers and one manager phones.

When the manager used to be here, we used to connect his phone to our mac and share the build with him. He is working remotely now. How shall I send the build to him now. His device is already provisioned and he is now running old version of our app (under development). We need to update his phone with the new build.

We are using XCode4.2 and Lion. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do you own OTA setup:

- Set up a simple webpage with a link to the `plist` that you will create in step 3
- do an adhoc build, then from `Organiser - Archive - Share`  enable the checkbox "Save for Enterprise Distribution"
- enter the URL of your simple web page from step one and a Title, save it
- upload `ipa` and `plist` file to the simple webpage
- email Url of simple web page to `manager` and  ask `manager` to click on link in simple webpage

Should work from iOS 4 onwards. Remember to bump the bundle version each time you make a new build for `manager`. I did overwrite one adhoc build on the device with a newer build but official word in the docs is that the version should increase between installs.

Alternatively you could email the `ipa` and ask `manager` to drag&drop into iTunes, but this method will require a computer running iTunes. The first method will work from the device itself

EDIT:
Sorry meant to write plist, not ipa. The anchor in the simple webpage would be the plist:

`<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://<server>/<directory>/<name-of-plist-from-step3>`

The `Application URL` entered into the organizer window would be the ipa:
`http://<server>/<directory>/<name-of-ipa-from-step3>`